# How do you check which button started in the new activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two buttons which call the same Map activity. But the action to be performed in the new activity is different depending on which button is clicked. In my `MyMapsActivity`, how do I check which intent fired the new activity? I am relatively new to Android programming, so I am not sure if doing this is the right way.

```
case (R.id.location_button1):
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MyMapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
    break;

case (R.id.location_button1):
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MyMapsActivity.class);
    intent2.putExtra("address", address);
    startActivity(intent2);
    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an "extra" in on of your intents, you could use that to distinguish them.

In your `MyMapsActivity` simply get the intent with `getIntent`(), and then check if the "address" is present or not.

The docs on `Intent` explain how to get and set extras and such: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Thank you, I got it! it was so simple!

Comment: @kavya This is right. But you should use [`setAction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String))/ [`getAction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getAction()) to distinguish actions. Extras are additional data for each action.

Comment: @Lai Vung, Yes, implicit intents use action/data/category for resolution, and there is a lot more to intent/intentfilter resolution (hence I linked the docs), but in this case we're talking about explicit intents and keeping it simple.